# Error 401: Alamofire/Swift 3

Tags: swift

This code previously works, and suddenly after several works around it stopped and return an Error 401.

```
Alamofire.request(WebServices.URLS().TabDataURL, method: .post, parameters: reqParams).validate().responseJSON { response in

            let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode) //Get HTTP status code
            guard response.result.isSuccess, let value = response.result.value else {
                // FIXME:you need to handle errors.
                print("Status, Fetching News List:", statusCode)
                return
            }
```

I have check via Postman, the parameters are correct. Infact, I can also login (by passing 2 parameters). But when I want to pull in a JSON data from server, I am getting 401.

my main project doesn't have an error. but instead of returning the JSON data, it gave me an Error 401. my other projects (same code format, same server & parameters) is giving me this error.

***Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840*** "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.} it worked!

Also, I have check with my other projects -- it seemed I cannot connect aswell. So I suspect it could be because of Alamofire, or my Xcode?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: it seems to me thats its ok, you should have a problem on your server.

Comment: I also tried removing `validate()` but no effect.

Comment: this confusing. my on my server, it works fine. infact, my Android version working well.

Comment: please post error.

Comment: my main project doesn't have an error. but instead of returning the JSON data, it gave me an Error 401. 

my other projects (same code format, same server & parameters) is giving me this error.

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
it worked!`

Comment: Hi ,let's add encoding to `JSONEncoding.default`

Comment: Have you tried looking up HTTP 401 response? It's "unauthorized" which means the server is expecting some kind of authentication so it can check if you are allowed to access the resource. https://httpstatuses.com/401

Comment: I tried to print out the parameters required for the server. All are actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i think your server Response is not correct because, as error indicate object should not start with array same issue i come across tell backend developer to send response in dictionary,

> {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

```
let headers = [String: String]()// To add header if any
Alamofire.request(path,method: mType, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers) .responseJSON
                        { response in

                        //----- this code always works for me. & You don't need add header if not required.

                         if let JSON = response.result.value {
                                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200
                                    {
                                            successCompletionHandler(JSON as! NSDictionary)
                                    }
                                    else if response.response?.statusCode == 401
                                    {
                                            failureCompletionHandler(JSON as! NSDictionary)
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                            failureCompletionHandler(JSON as! NSDictionary)
                                    }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    print("error message")
                                    failureCompletionHandler([WSAPIConst.ERROR:WSAPIConst.ERROR_MESSAGE])
                            }


                         }
```

Comment: On Postman, i have this header:     
`let headers: HTTPHeaders = [  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]`, it works. However when I added this to my code it still returns 401

Comment: I added `JSONEncoding.default`, it returns error 200

Comment: strange, because when i check the data (if there's really something on my JSONData.. `print("the data",response.data!)` it gives me `the data 2111 bytes`

Comment: statusCode 200 - without passing a parameter, statusCode 401 - with parameter, statuscode 500 - without the header

Comment: thank you. unfortunately i am still getting the same error. :-(